# DevExpress XtraGrid Control with checkBoxEdit column

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I've a DevExpress [XtraGrid](http://devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Grid/) control with three columns and a unbound checkBoxEdit column for users to select when deleting items from the grid. I'm able to add the checkBoxEdit on the xtraGrid. However, i don't have any idea as to how i can get the selected lists' primary key(s) to be deleted. Any idea is highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: what technologies (asp.net,asp.net mvc,WPF,WinForms)?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm using WinForms

Comment: Consider expanding your data object with a boolean property, e.g.  "markdeleted". No more need for an unbound column and its infrastructure code.

Comment: @StephanKeller: Unbound columns is agile approach to extend you data objects and implement the functionality described by topic starter. I believe that extending the data source is the worst approach in this situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can use the following approach:

```
void InitGrid() {
    gridControl1.DataSource = new List<Person> { 
        new Person(){ ID = 0 }, 
        new Person(){ ID = 1 }, 
        new Person(){ ID = 2 }
    };
    gridView.Columns["ID"].Visible = false;
    gridView.Columns.Add(new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Columns.GridColumn()
    {
        UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean,
        Caption = "Mark as Deleted",
        FieldName = "IsDeleted",
        Visible = true,
    });
}
IDictionary<int, object> selectedRows = new Dictionary<int, object>();
void gridView1_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, CustomColumnDataEventArgs e) {
    int id = (int)gridView.GetListSourceRowCellValue(e.ListSourceRowIndex, gridView.Columns["ID"]);
    if(e.IsGetData) 
        e.Value = selectedRows.ContainsKey(id);
    else {
        if(!(bool)e.Value)
            selectedRows.Remove(id);
        else selectedRows.Add(id, e.Row);
    }
}
void OnDelete(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
    //... Here you can iterate thought selectedRows dictionary
}
//
class Person {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Age { get; set; }
}
```

Related help topics:

- [ColumnView.CustomUnboundColumnData Event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic)
- [ColumnView.GetListSourceRowCellValue Method](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_GetListSourceRowCellValuetopic946)

Comment: @user758961: [You should always accept right answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)