# How to Select row using checkedit gridcontrol devexpress?

Tags: c#, checkbox, devexpress, gridcontrol

I have a WinForm using C# in my coding, and I use gridcontrol Devexpress 2010 to show the data contact list.

[Here is my form](https://www.dropbox.com/s/453klrmp4q61tz3/code.PNG)

After selecting those lists I get the value from gridcontrol that I select and press the button OK to get it. I don't know the code.

Anyone can suggest me.

Answer (score 3):

First of all i suggest you to the KB article: [How to select rows via an unbound checkbox column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A371)

> Starting with version 13.2, the GridView in the XtraGrid control
> provides a built-in checkbox column for multiple row selection. See
> the following help topic to learn more: [Multiple Row Selection via
> Built-In Check Column](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16439)
>
> In versions prior to 13.2, you can use the following two methods to
> manually implement a column for row selection:
>
> 1. Add a Boolean data column to your data source that will maintain the selected state of rows.
> 2. Use an unbound grid column.
>
> The first approach is easy to implement, but adding "dummy" columns to
> data is often forbidden due to the constraints of an application's
> business logic.
>
> *The second approach is clarified below.*
>
> Create an array that will store the selected states of rows.  Create
> an [Unbound Column](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) whose values will be in sync with the array.
> Write a **CustomUnboundColumnData** event handler to get/set unbound
> column values.
> See perfect example of this here:
> [DevExpress XtraGrid Control with checkBoxEdit column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347505/devexpress-xtragrid-control-with-checkboxedit-column)

**References:**
[DevExpress Example:Multiple selection using checkbox (web style)](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E1271)

Hope this help..

Comment: that link is refers to devexpress 2013 and higher,..but i still didn't find tutorial for devexpress 2010....most of them give me some suggest that i must changing my devexpress version to devexpress 2013...