# DevExpress checkedit on GridControl (Gridview)

Tags: devexpress

I am using Devexpress GridControl and I listed the data (personel informations) on the grid. But I want to add checkEdit on GridControl/Gridview. This checkEdit will be select or unselect to the incoming data. How can I do this?

Thanks,
Best Regards,

Answer (score 1):

> Starting with version 13.2, the GridView in the XtraGrid control
>   provides a built-in checkbox column for multiple row selection. See
>   the following help topic to learn more: [Multiple Row Selection via
>   Built-In Check Column](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16439)

References:
[How to Select row using checkedit gridcontrol devexpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29359705/how-to-select-row-using-checkedit-gridcontrol-devexpress)