# How do I select more than one Check edit in my Devexpress Grid Control?

Tags: c#-4.0, devexpress

I have a grid control with a single bound column called Warehouse and a second unbound column with a repository check edit called Active. I tried using the documentation from Devexpress but I am still having trouble succeeding. I need to be able to set a specific group of warehouses as active. Any advice will be much appreciated.

Comment: Could you simply add a (bool) property for Active and make it a bound column instead of an unbound one?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the [GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridMultiSelectModeEnumtopic) mode. 
When this mode is active in GridView, the GridView displays an additional 'Check' column containing check boxes in each row. An end-user can toggle check boxes to change row selection. Row selection via the keyboard and mouse are also supported.

Related help-topics:
[Multiple Row and Cell Selection](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument711)
[Multiple Row Selection via Built-In Check Column](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16439)

Comment: Thanks Dmitry. This was very useful and I managed to select multiple check boxes with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this - [How to select rows via an unbound checkbox column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A371)

Starting with version 13.2, the GridView in the XtraGrid control provides a built-in checkbox column for multiple row selection. See the following help topic to learn more: [Multiple Row Selection via Built-In Check Column](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument16439)

In versions prior to 13.2, you can use the following two methods to manually implement a column for row selection:

1. Add a Boolean data column to your data source that will maintain the selected state of rows.
2. Use an unbound grid column.**[You have adopted this one]**

The first approach is easy to implement, but adding "dummy" columns to data is often forbidden due to the constraints of an application's business logic.

The second approach is clarified below.

Create an array that will store the selected states of rows. 
Create an [Unbound Column](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument1477) whose values will be in sync with the array. Write a [CustomUnboundColumnData event](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_CustomUnboundColumnDatatopic) handler to get/set unbound column values.

> The values of the custom unbound column must be stored and retrieved
>   manually when GridView.CustomUnboundColumnData is fired (for
>   e.IsSetData and e.IsGetData respectively)

Reference these example and knowledge base with sample code also..
[Unbound checkbox column in grid](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q477718)
[Allow multiple selection of checkedits in xtragrid column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q520058)
[How to create and populate an unbound column](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E3354)
[How to use an unbound check box column to select grid rows](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E990)
[DevExpress XtraGrid Control with checkBoxEdit column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347505/devexpress-xtragrid-control-with-checkboxedit-column)

Comment: Thank you Niranjan for your suggestion.